# {{content-for 'head'}} Ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've been using Yeoman ember generator for the past 1 month and now, I'd like to give ember-cli a try.

I run the generator and launch the app, everything works fine.

```
ember new my-new-app
ember server
```

but I'd like to know how does

```
{{content-for 'head'}}
```

in app/index.html works?

When looking at other examples from http://www.ember-cli.com/#tutorials, none of them are using this particular helper? Is it because they are using older version of ember-cli? Why weren't they using this content-for helper?

I'm pretty sure that ember.js doesn't have this content-for helper in default, so I'm guessing ember-cli wrote it somewhere? Where is it and what is it for?

Also, when I inspect the element of my-new-app page, the div tag of 'Welcome to Ember.js' appeared at the body tag instead of head tag? How is that possible? {{mind-blown}}

( in app/index.html,    {{content-for 'head'}}    is placed inside head tag)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It was recently added to ember-cli based on [this discussion](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2118).

Here is the relevant code from the [commit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/commit/a2909a3e514aa34219c131b92dc80183eee7a489):

```
EmberApp.prototype.contentFor = function(config, match, type) {
  var content = [];

  if (type === 'head') {
    content.push(calculateBaseTag(config));

    content.push('<meta name="' + config.modulePrefix + '/config/environment" ' +
                 'content="' + escape(JSON.stringify(config)) + '">');
  }

  content = this.project.addons.reduce(function(content, addon) {
    if (addon.contentFor) {
      return content.concat(addon.contentFor(type, config));
    }

    return content;
  }, content);

  return content.join('\n');
};
```

Comment: For some additional context see https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-inline-content

Answer (score 21):

From [Ember CLI guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/):

> app/index.html
>
> The `app/index.html` file lays the foundation for your application.
>   This is where the basic DOM structure is laid out, the title attribute
>   is set and stylesheet/javascript includes are done. In addition to
>   this, `app/index.html` includes multiple hooks - `{{content-for
>   'head'}}` and `{{content-for 'body'}}` - that can be used by Addons to
>   inject content into your application’s `head` or `body`. These hooks
>   need to be left in place for your application to function properly,
>   but they can be safely ignored unless you are working directly with a
>   particular addon.

I was actually looking for where `Welcome to Ember.js`is coming from (which is obviously in `app\templates\application.hbs`), but first stumbled upon `content-for` helpers.

Comment: even in an addon, how do you inject into head