# previous {{content-for 'head'}} ember-cli post was not answered thoroughly

Tags: ember-cli

This question was not thoroughly answered here:  [[{{content-for 'head'}} Ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210367/content-for-head-ember-cli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210367/content-for-head-ember-cli)

In the latest version of ember-cli, {{content-for 'head'}} is required in index.html (breaks when I remove it) with zero explanation about it in the docs. I got as far as reading about ember-cli-inline-content here: https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-inline-content. But where is 'head' defined in the latest ember-cli? Can someone explain this more thoroughly please?

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](http://www.ember-cli.com/#appindexhtml) have been updated with a bit more detail on what these hooks are, but the gist is that these are used to allow for ember-cli addons to inject content into the head of your document. They don't offer much beyond that for you to use directly, but they do need to be left in your `index.html` file so that they are available for any addons you may or may not use.

Comment: So to clarify, if you wanted to add a link to an external css file, you would just modify `index.html` and not use the `{{content-for 'head'}}` functionality?