# Is it possible to use EmberJS components in the index.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I searched through a good amount of the documentation and did some decent research online but can't seem to find a definitive answer on this.

Is is possible to use components from EmberJS inside the index.html file?

I notice they use **{{content-for "body"}}** and such, but I don't quite understand why/how they use it.

Comment: It is not. `{{content-for` is a special directive so that addons can add content to said sections. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210367/content-for-head-ember-cli for related answers.

Comment: To ensure that it is not an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), why do you want to do this?